# Can't acces VM created with vagrant and running tomcat from host machine

Tags: tomcat, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm working on a school project where we need to create different application severs with virtualbox. One of these is a CentOS minimal install with tomcat and java. Because these vm's need to be able to be quickly recreated, I've automated this using vagrant.

I've created my own vagrant box with tomcat, java and mysql already installed.
This is my vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |o|
o.vm.box = "CentOS"
o.vm.box_url = "C://Users/Niels/GO3/opdracht01/CentOS_vagrant"
o.vm.synced_folder "./app", "/var/wwww/", create:true
o.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.55.55"
end
```

In the app folder on my host machine is a phpinfo page.

Could someone please provide any help? I've bee trying out solutions to similar problems but none have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a php info page with a tomcat server, which wont work, since tomcat does not serve php.

To test your tomcat server, you can get the `sample.war` application from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/ . After placing the `sample.war` in `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`, you should be able to load it from inside the guest with `curl http://localhost:8080/sample/`

Next thing to check is whether your iptables are set up correctly to allow access on port 8080 (this is the default port for tomcat). You can view the loaded iptables with the command `iptables -L`

If everything is set up correctly you should be able to load the sample app trough `http://192.168.55.55:8080/sample/`

To make things smoother you could also set up port forwarding allowing you to use localhost:8080 from the host os, to reach your tomcat server.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Using the sample.war file it worked. Although there is a problem with my vagrant box: as it seemed none of the software I installed was there when I used it.